# Networking between Indy10 and System.Net.Sockets

Tags: c#, delphi, uwp, pascal, indy10

Me and my partner working on a project where my partner is developing in Pascal and using Indy10 socket for networking and I'm developing under C# in an UWP project. Therefore for networking I have to use streamsocket namespace.

The problem is, that my partner uses ReadStream method with -1 and false parameters, that mean that the length of the receiving stream is indetermined. Therefore, I have to send a length prefix calculated (in this case I use BitConverter.GetBytes method) from the data in my stream (for example using DataWriter class) continued with the data itself. 
But Indy10 socket don't receives nothing. It looks like it stucks on waiting for the packet or I don't know.

Does anybody hit that problem? Please help, we've been looking after the solution for about two weeks. I had read all the similar questions here in StackOverflow, a blog about the use of framing, delimitering. Searched for solution in Indy Socket source code itself. 
Please help!

**UPDATE 1**
C# code. In this case I am sending from a WPF application. The logic, how streams are used in UWP are almost the same, just using StreamSocket and DataWriter.

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient(hostTextBox.Text, int.Parse(portTextBox.Text));

Byte[] byteMessage = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(messageTextBox.Text);
Byte[] lenghtPrefix = BitConverter.GetBytes(byteMessage.Length);
Byte[] concatedData = new byte[lenghtPrefix.Length + byteMessage.Length];
lenghtPrefix.CopyTo(concatedData, 0);
byteMessage.CopyTo(concatedData, lenghtPrefix.Length);

NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
writer.Write(concatedData);
writer.Flush();

stream.Close();
client.Close();
```

But we have tried this solution too:

```
Byte[] byteMessage = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(messageTextBox.Text);
Byte[] lenghtPrefix = BitConverter.GetBytes(byteMessage.Length);

Socket socket = new Socket(SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
socket.Connect(hostTextBox.Text, int.Parse(portTextBox.Text));

socket.Send(lenghtPrefix, SocketFlags.None);
socket.SendBufferSize = byteMessage.Length;
socket.Send(byteMessage, SocketFlags.None);

socket.Close();
```

Pascal code on the server side, waiting for stream. It is crucial to receive in this way, because the software's other modules (also written in Pascal using Indy10) communicating with the server in this way.

```
function Receive(const AContext: TIdContext): string;
var
  Stream: TMemoryStream;
begin
  try
    Result := '';
    Stream := TMemoryStream.Create;
    if  AContext.Connection.Connected then
      AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadStream(Stream, -1, False);
  finally
    Result := UnPackStream(Stream);
    Stream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: try sniffing packets with Wireshark to see what if you're not sending right or he's not receiving right.

Comment: We can't debug code we can't see based on a somewhat vague description of what it does and how it's behaving.

Comment: Have you tried the official [StreamSocket sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/StreamSocket) on GitHub? This sample contains both receive and send function. And while sending data, it also write the length of the content as UINT32 value before the content. You can use this sample to identify whether the problem is in your client side or server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, here is the solution. We worked on that all day. We used Synapse socket as a reference. In the end here is the code under UWP, and we tested it in other desktop projects (WPF, Winforms) too (with `TcpClient` and `NetworkStream`).
`BitConverter` and prefixing the hole stream with a number didn't worked, because Indy waits for the length in binary format, therefore the byte array have to contain values representing the binary length. **I hope it will help others having similar problem!**

```
Windows.Networking.Sockets.StreamSocket socket = new Windows.Networking.Sockets.StreamSocket();
Windows.Networking.HostName serverHost = new Windows.Networking.HostName(hostTextBox.Text);
string serverPort = portTextBox.Text;
await socket.ConnectAsync(serverHost, serverPort);

//Write data to the server.
DataWriter writer = new DataWriter(socket.OutputStream);

byte[] data = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(messageTextBox.Text);
byte[] size = new byte[4];

ushort x = (ushort)(data.Length >> 16);
ushort y = (ushort)(data.Length);
size[0] = (byte)(x / 256);
size[1] = (byte)(x % 256);
size[2] = (byte)(y / 256);
size[3] = (byte)(y % 256);

writer.WriteBytes(size);
writer.WriteBytes(data);
await writer.StoreAsync();
await writer.FlushAsync();

writer.DetachStream();

//Read response.
var bytes = new byte[4];

DataReader reader = new DataReader(socket.InputStream);
await reader.LoadAsync(4);

reader.ReadBytes(bytes);
int length = bytes[0] * 256 * 256 * 256 + bytes[1] * 256 * 256 + bytes[2] * 256 + bytes[3];

byte[] dat = new byte[length];
var count = await reader.LoadAsync((uint)length);
reader.ReadBytes(dat);

responseTextBlock.Text = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(dat);

reader.DetachStream();
socket.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 0):

When calling `TIdIOHandler.ReadStream()` in Indy, if `AByteCount` is -1 and `AReadUntilDisconnect` is False, `ReadStream()` will read the first 4 bytes (Int32) or 8 bytes (Int64) (depending on the value of the `TIdIOHandler.LargeStream` property) and interpret them as an integer in network byte order (big-endian), then read the number of bytes specified by that integer (if greater than 0).

The main problem with your first C# example is that you are using a `StreamWriter`, which is designed for sending text, not binary data. If you try to write a `Byte[]` array with a `StreamWriter`, it will not be sent as-is, it will be formatted to a textual representation that is not compatible with Indy.  You don't need the `StreamWriter`, you can use the `NetworkStream` as-is, it has a `Write()` method for `Byte[]` data. Or use a `BinaryWriter`.

Another problem with both C# examples is that you are using `BitConverter` without taking endian into account. Its `GetBytes(Int32)` method creates an array of bytes in the same endian as the calling machine's architecture. Windows is primarily a little-endian environment, but `ReadStream()` is expecting the integer bytes in big-endian.

Try something more like this:

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient(hostTextBox.Text, int.Parse(portTextBox.Text));

Byte[] byteMessage = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(messageTextBox.Text);
Byte[] lengthPrefix = BitConverter.GetBytes(byteMessage.Length);
if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
     Array.Reverse(lengthPrefix);

NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
stream.Write(lengthPrefix, 0, lengthPrefix.Length);
stream.Write(byteMessage, 0, byteMessage.Length);

stream.Close();
client.Close();
```

Or this:

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient(hostTextBox.Text, int.Parse(portTextBox.Text));

Byte[] byteMessage = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(messageTextBox.Text);
Byte[] lengthPrefix = BitConverter.GetBytes(byteMessage.Length);
if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
     Array.Reverse(lengthPrefix);

NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(stream);

// BinaryWriter.Write(Int32) writes in little-endian only,
// so you still need to use Write(Byte[]) for the length value...
writer.Write(lengthPrefix); 
writer.Write(byteMessage)
writer.Flush();

stream.Close();
client.Close();
```

Comment: You are true, using StreamWriter sometimes sends messy data. Anyway,  I did not tried reversing the length prefix array. I'll give it a try. I really appreciate your help!